# How to scroll li item into visibile area of the window using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to scroll the list item on clicking another element (say image) such that it is visible.

what i am trying to do?
i have a list that contains elements. each list item has some image assocated to it. on clicking image seen in screen it should highlight the respective list item.

I am using scroll using css. but then if the list item is somewhere below and the user clicks the image this list item gets highlighted and is invisible unless user scrolls the list.

i want the highlighted list item to be visible to user when he clicks image corresponding to it.

What i have tried so far?

```
class List extends react.purecomponent {
     handle_image_clicked = drawing => {
         this.props.on_highlight_item(this.props.items.find(t => t.id 
         === image.item_id)); // this function basically finds the item id 
         //that for which the image is selected
         const elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
         elmnt.length > 0 && elmnt[0].scrollIntoView();
     };

     render = () => {
         return (
             <ul>
                {state.items.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <Fragment>
                            <Item>{item.name}</Item> 
                            <Images
                                images={item.images}
                                highlighted_item_id= 
                                {props.highlighted_item_id}
                                on_image_selected= 
                                this.handle_drawing_clicked}/>}
                        </Fragment>);
                 }
             </ul>
         );
     }
 }


 class Item extends react.purecomponent {
     render = () => {
         return (
             <li className={props.highlighted ? 'selected' : ''}>
                 <div></div>
             </li>
         );
     }
 }

class Images extend react.purecomponent {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.on_image_selected}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now this works meaning shows the highlighted list item in visible area (scrolls it to the visible view). but initially i get elmnt undefined...i suppose that's because the element with class selected is not rendered...how can i fix this. such that i don't get this error.

or otherwise how can i do this without using getelementbyclassname approach.

could someone help me with this thanks.

Comment: Can you not just check for elmnt?
`if (elmnt && elmnt.length > 0) elmnt[0].scrollIntoView();`

Comment: if i used it in componentdidupdate it worked...instead of using getelementbyclasname will it be possible to do same thing with ref? if so how could i do it thanks.